# Scons LIBS linking, how to remove duplicate LIBS?

Tags: scons

We use indirection when specifying library dependencies, for instance,

```
env.Program(TARGET, SOURCE, LIBS = [ $LIBS_A, $LIBS_B, $LIBS_C ])
```

LIBS_A, LIBS_B, and LIBS_C are specified in other SConscript files.

Suppose:

```
LIBS_A/Sconscript has  LIBS_A = [ foo, bar, baz ]
LIBS_B/Sconscript has  LIBS_B = [ foo, bar, bat ]
LIBS_C/Sconscript has  LIBS_C = [ foo, bar, ben ]
```

Then the final linker line will have:

```
-lfoo -lbar -lbaz -lfoo -lbar -lbat -lfoo -lbar -lben
```

How can we remove duplicates and have the linker line read:

```
-lfoo -lbar -lbaz -lbat -lben
```

Comment: Hmm, if you want all those libs appearing only once, then you have to specify them only once for "LIBS". Giving a lib several times might actually make sense when circular dependencies between libraries and objects are involved...so SCons won't be able to resolve this automatically.

Comment: It would be helpful if the sample code you present is actually runnable.. the env.Program cannot work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this. files fully listed.

main.cxx

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

SConstruct

```
env=Environment()

Export('env')

for l in ['A','B','C']:
    env.SConscript("LIBS_%s/SConscript"%l)

env.Program('myprogram',['main.cxx'], LIBS = list(set(env['LIBS_A'] + env['LIBS_B'] + env['LIBS_C'])))
```

LIBS_A/SConscript
    Import('env')

```
env['LIBS_A'] = ['foo','bar','baz']
```

LIBS_B/SConscript
    Import('env')

```
env['LIBS_B'] = ['foo','bar','bat']
```

LIBS_C/SConscript
    Import('env')

```
env['LIBS_C'] = ['foo','bar','ben']
```

Yields:

> g++ -o myprogram main.o -lbaz -lbat -lfoo -lbar -lben

If none of those would work for you, here's a more complicated way that should:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def __call__(self, target, source, env, for_signature):
        print "LIBS_A: %s  LIBS_B: %s"%(env['LIBS_A'],env['LIBS_B'])
        rc = list(set(env['LIBS_A']+env['LIBS_B']))
        print "Unique: %s"%rc
        print "SIG:%s"%for_signature
        return rc

# Will call our foo method to uniquify LIBS_*
env=Environment(FOO=foo, BAR="${FOO('$LIBS_A $LIBS_B')}")

env.Command('foo.XXXXX','foo.in',action="echo LIBS: $LIBS",LIBS="$BAR",
            LIBS_A=['a','b','c','d','e','f','f','b'],
            LIBS_B=['b','d','e','g','x'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I do not see this working for our situation. I did try it anyway, and received this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list':

I think the reason this does not work is because we use the $ notation (to defer interpolation until the command is actually invoked as opposed to when it's read by scons). This is important because the value that's being referred to might not be complete at the time it's read. So we use $LIB_A and $LIB_B and $LIB_C. Those value in turn may also use the $ notation within their SConscripts.

Comment: The SConscripts in the for loop would have to define their local lib dependencies like so:  env['LIBS_A'] = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ], ... and so on,
so that the SConstruct could then use the $LIBS_A notation. The key thing to note is the use of the $ notation. This is because say LIBS_B depended on LIBS_Z, so it would be defined like so env['LIBS_B'] = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', '$LIBS_Z' ], thus bringing in LIBS_Z dependencies w/o having to know them. Imagine this happening for dozens and dozens of libs, we get a linker command that has dozens of duplicate libs because the of the dependency graph.

Comment: The above would work if you knew that you could have all the SConscript statements prior to your Program statement.  Then you'd do something like; env['LIBS_A']= []. env['LIBS_A'] += env.Library('mylibrary',[sources])  for each library built in the SConscript.  This is simpler that what you are suggesting. Would this work for you?  Remember that the order of SConscripts does matter in building whatever python datastructures are used in your SConscript/SConstruct. But of course that only builds the dependancy tree and shouldn't impact the order of command execution.

Comment: That's exactly the issue, is that we cannot impose the order in which SConscripts are read. We have 60+ various binaries (Program() calls) within our codebase so this would be tough constraint to impose. It would be nice if there was a Unique() routine that could be called to filter out duplicates.

Comment: O.k. dumb question, but is it actually doing any harm besides long command lines? If they're shared libraries it shouldn't matter. If their static, it may be important to have them listed multiple times.

Comment: There is a way to do what you want. Let me dig a bit. I think you can change the routine which expands the libs into command line to removed duplicates on expansion.

Comment: It's causing no harm, just adding a full screen to the linker line in the build output, when it should just be a couple of lines. Would make it hard to see if you wanted to know if one lib is buried in there among the dozens and dozens of duplicates.

Comment: Right, I thought of doing that, modifying the scons code. That's how I first new I could do what I'm doing, as I was oringally on scons 2.37 and I went online to look at the source code and found the routine I needed, and discovered it had been introduced SINCE 2.37, so I knew to upgrade and then this capability of using '$VAR' began working. Now we just need to remove duplicates.

Comment: No need to modify the scons code.  You can do everything you need in your SConstruct/SConscripts.

Comment: See the manpage: http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html  search for "class foo(object):" I believe that's the trick.

Comment: We're on the right track. But not quite there for my exact situation. But let's just say I have a top-level MYLIBS = [ '$LIBS_A' '$LIBS_B' 'boost_system', env['THIRDPARTY']['glog']['TARGET'] ]

What I get in your print statement is:

MYLIBS: ['$LIBS_A', '$LIBS_B', 'boost_system', ['glog', 'gflags']]

So LIBS_A and LIBS_B are not resolving, when they should.

Also, I get link line that has:
"-l<SCons.Script.foo object at 0x2dc1990>"

Comment: Also, why do we have to have FOO=foo and we can't just refer to foo directly?  ${foo()} vs ${FOO()}?

Comment: Okay, I added a Flatten() call and that resolved the nested array, but we're still not resolving the $LIBS_A and $LIBS_B (recall, these in turn are added to the environment in other SConscripts and they too refer to other recursively defined libs, i.e. LIBS_A = [ '$LIBS_C', 'myproj_a' ]

Comment: Okay, solved it:

LIST = env.subst(env['MYLIBS'])                                                                   
print LIST
rc = list(set(LIST[0].split()))  
Just had to add the subst to resolve the $LIBS_A, and then that was all coming back as a single string so had to split it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Big thanks to @bdbaddog

```
class uniquify_libs(object):
  def __init__(self, arg):
    self.arg = arg 

  def __call__(self, target, source, env, for_signature):
    rc = list(set(env.subst(env[self.arg])[0].split()))
    return rc

LIBS = ['$LIBS_A', '$LIBS_B'] ## defined in other SConscripts

Program(
  target  = TARGET,
  source  = SOURCE,
  UNIQUE  = uniquify_libs,
  MYLIBS  = LIBS,
  LIBS    = "${UNIQUE('MYLIBS')}",
)
```

Comment: You are most welcome. Was an interesting issue to address. :)